# What to do for answers that come after an accepted answer and still have the same solution?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-answers

On a few of my questions, I see newer answers come after an accepted answer and yet add nothing useful. I wonder why do they even post such answers. Maybe they want to get more reputation? So what can we do to such answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they answer the question but add nothing, leave them be. If you think they answer the question and add something to the existing answers, upvote them. If you think they are poor answers and do not answer the question or answer the question inadequately, downvote them and add a comment.